# delete view using popup in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

am using jquery code to popup my view.i want to delete data through this popup...But by using the following code,only popup is coming not performing deleting action,the jquery code is shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.del').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    custom_confirm('pleaseNote:',
        function () {
            var sel = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/default1/Delete/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: sel },
                success: function (result) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }, error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
});
function custom_confirm(prompt, action, title) {
      $("#confirm").dialog({
        buttons: {
            'Proceed': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $('#confirm').dialog({ modal: true });
                action();
            },
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

})
and my view code is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete",new { id = item.studentID }, new { @class="del"})
                  <div id="confirm" style="display: none"></div>
```

and controller action is

```
[HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id=0)
    {
        student student = db.students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        db.students.Remove(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: ajax url = url: `'/default1/Delete/',` but method name: `DeleteConfirmed`

Comment: Decorate the Action Method like below. `[ActionName("Delete")] public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id=0)`

Comment: Don't hardcode the url like this `url: '/default1/Delete/'` it should be like `"Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {area = "AreaName"})"`

Comment: Like @PKKG said, if you use a hardcoded url like this in a partialview  ( I assume this is partial ) your url could get mangled. It will try to access /default1/default1/Delete, which doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are selecting the href attribute:

```
var sel = $(this).attr('href');
```

and then passing it as id parameter in the AJAX request:

```
data: { id: sel }
```

Now looking at your `DeleteConfirmed` controller action, it expects that the `id` parameter be an integer value. But the `href` is not an integer. That's why your controller action is never invoked.

Also `$(this)` inside the action is not what you think it is.

So here's how you could proceed:

```
custom_confirm('pleaseNote:', function () {
    var url = $('.del').attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            $(this).remove();
        }, error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: or we could say `var sel = $('.del').attr('id');` ?

Comment: No, you can't say that. `$(this)` is the dialog so this will return `confirm`.

Comment: I've already checked. Have you seen where is the `action` parameter being called? Inside the `'Proceed'` button click of the dialog. And you know what `this` is referring to in this callback? Check it out.